# Combination of docking and anchoring behaviours in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, docking

Today I'm trying to use c# to fit a number of windows controls onto a panel sequentially.
I would like them to dock to the top so that I can then use BringToFront() to stack them up.

HOWEVER I would also like them to be centred. Currently, docking behaviour forces the controls to the left of the screen (however much I resize and change the location property)

I then tried to anchor my controls to the top of the panel instead. This enabled the controls to be centred and also let me resize them but anchoring has no stacking behaviour and each control overwrites the previous one.

I have researched this extensively for hours and have found no answers to this question. Is it possible to use either or both of these properties to stack my controls in the centre of the panel?

My code currently stands as so:

```
//Docking 
userControl.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
userControl.Width = 633;
userControl.Left = (pnlRules.Width - userControl.Width) / 2; //doesn't work
Point location = new Point(((pnlRules.Width - userControl.Width) / 2), 0);
userControl.Location = location; //doesn't work
userControl.BringToFront();
```

OR

```
//Anchoring
userControl.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Top;
Point location = new Point(((pnlRules.Width - userControl.Width) / 2), 0);
userControl.Location = location;
userControl.BringToFront(); //doesn't work
```

My outputs are either stacked controls bound to the left panel edge (docking) or overlapping controls beautifully resized and centred (anchoring)

Thanks :)
Anya

Edit:
This captions my problem quite nicely:
http://www.techrepublic.com/article/manage-winform-controls-using-the-anchor-and-dock-properties/

This explains that using docking, the controls can be stacked next to each other. I would just like the docked, stacked controls to not be bound to the left edge of the panel.

Comment: Check [`TableLayoutPanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.aspx), it has layout spells. Regarding `BringToFront()`, instead of having something behind and then bring to front you can have it invisible (`Visible = false`) and properly layouted, so that making it visible will position it correctly.

Comment: Not clear what you are trying to do. If you *BringToFront* a control and then add a new one on top of it then it will not be visible.

Comment: I'm currently using BringToFront() to set the z-order of my controls, I want every control on the page to be visible - as a list of controls. I am adding the controls one at a time and need them to add onto the end of the existing list.

Comment: That doesn't make sense.  Do you know what "z-order" is?  If you pile them up on top of one another, by definition only the topmost will be visible.

Comment: Using the BringToFront() on the docked controls does make them line up rather than pile on top of one another. I believe z-order is the correct term for this. Please correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: OK, I figured out the actual problem here. The anchor and dock properties are mutually exclusive. As soon as you use one, the other resets to default. The issue here is that anchor default is top,left which is why all my controls are hugging the left wall.

Question: how can I change the default value of anchor to none? (not found in properties design view)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to use a combination of docking and anchoring. A TableLayoutPanel may have worked here but I was tied to a simple Panel.

The fix was to use padding to force the control to centre:

```
userControl.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
pnlParent.Padding = new Padding((pnlParent.Width - userControl.Width) / 2, 0, 0, 0);
userControl.BringToFront();
```